# Multiple AJAX Calls and DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

My team and I have built a dynamic website that tracks a variety of different information on customers. When a user is selected from a grid, multiple ajax calls are made to various methods, and each of these get a new instance of DbContext.

```
   public JsonResult GetPaymentInfo(int id = 0)
    {
        var paymentInfo = new PaymentInfo();
        using (var data = new DashboardModels())
        {
            paymentInfo = data.PaymentInfo.Where(p => p.AccountId == id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return Json(JsonResponseFactory.SuccessResponse(paymentInfo), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```

Similar to this.

What would be the recommended way to fire those methods asynchronously still (as they all return Json Data to their respective jQuery Ajax Calls) in relation to the DbContext? Should I be sharing the same DbContext as it's a single transaction? And if so, can someone assist me in moving in this direction?

Comment: Are you noticing any performance problems with different DbContext objects?  I personally don't think using different DbContext object's is bad, especially since you are streaming the data as JSON.

Comment: I honestly haven't noticed a decrease in performance locally, but I'm going to publish to about 140 vicious call center/Sales personnel and wanted to make sure I was going about this the right way. Honestly, my only issue used to be the Entities slowly growing (fixed by switching to the "Using" statements and disposing of the context manually in some cases). Using new contexts per request it's been seemingly stable. (there are 7 method calls that can happen in rapid succession, and rapid clicking results in 7-10% cpu usage)

Comment: Brian Mains +1
There is not like a problem. Views on the knockoutjs or angularjs use.

Comment: Ok, we are live now, W3wp.exe was hovering around 30% cpu under heavy use, now seems to be about 0-4%. Still spiking to 80+ on page load, but we're doubling the RAM to 4 gigs in the morning, so that should clear up our GC times nicely. Thank you for the insight Brian, if you'd like to make an actual answer for others who may be wondering the same I will gladly accept. Also, server seems to be using 100M less memory (limit set to 600M, running at 499,800k